# How to return user to incomplete form without making user retype completed fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Simple question, but damned if I can find the answer.  Currently if a user doesn't check the "terms" checkbox, my "return false" javascript statement wipes out the whole form.  Thus, user has to retype all the fields that were previously completed.

```
if( !($("#checkbox-1").is(":checked")) ){//If terms box is not checked
alert ("Please check the terms box...");    
return false;
 }
```

Using jQuery and jQuery Mobile

Comment: can you store the data in the model/viewbag/session variables, the populate/bind onLoad?

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: ?? not sure what that is...  localStorage?

Comment: Is this an MVC site? WebForms? etc???

Comment: How is that code being called?

Comment: code being called by JQM button/submit.

Answer (score 0):

Taken straight from the JQuery API reference example, changed to use your checkbox

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if( ($("#checkbox-1").is(":checked")) ){//If terms box is checked //more readable       
  return
 }    

  event.preventDefault();
  alert ("Please check the terms box..."); 
});
```

Comment: awe Jeez.  Life too short to worry about all that junk.  Their agreement and possible workarounds.....  i ain't worried.  Just needs something simple to help them out.

Comment: OK.  There's a pony in there somewhere.  Trying it now.  Thanks

Comment: Tried it.  if the checkbox is not checked......  above does not send them back to form.....

Comment: There was an extra curly brace.

Comment: yeah.  I caught that and removed it.

Comment: Hmmm.  so the jQM checkbox is actually a  an "input" part of a JQM < fieldset data-role="controlgroup"  > So, is separate from the HTML "FORM".  I tried moving the </form> tag to include the fieldset DIV.  Still doesn't return when checkbox not checked.